# Rotating emulator ctrl f11 and 7 & 9 keys

Tags: android

I have tried to rotate the emulator while it is running by hitting and holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>f11</kbd> but nothing happens. I also have read I need to switch off numlock which I dont have and hit <kbd>7</kbd> & <kbd>9</kbd>. I tried hitting <kbd>7</kbd> & <kbd>9</kbd>  but the emulator does not rotate. If any one has experienced this or knows another way I would highly appreciate a response. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Switching from Portrait to landscape mode & vice-versa - > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>

Both works on emulator

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it by using the following: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> +  <kbd>F11</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Use the ctrl key on the left side of the keyboard. Don't ask my why, but if I use the right one and press F11 it doesn't do anything, but using the left one does.